# Using highcharter to return multiple data with Shiny

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

I wanted to create a multiple line chart with draggable points and return the data of individual points back to the Shiny server into a datatable. I am not sure how to code this up. Is there a way to return a change to the myZax line graph back to the data table m_data?

server.R code

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(data.table)


myData <- data.table(x=2012:2016, data.frame(myYax = c(3900,  4200,  5700,  8500, 11900), myZax=c(3900,  4200,  500,  800, 1000)))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  #Make a copy of the data table. It will be run only once when use opens the application
  m_data <- myData

  output$text1 <- renderText({ 
    paste("You have selected ",input$xaxis_name)
  })

  output$text2 <- renderText({ 
    paste("You have selected ",input$yaxis_name)
  })

  output$view <- renderTable({                      
                      m_data[x==input$xaxis_name]$myYax = input$yaxis_name                      
                      m_data})

  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({    
    hc <- highchart() %>% 
      hc_chart(type = "line", animation=FALSE) %>% 
      hc_title(text = "A simple demo") %>% 
      hc_subtitle(text = "A subtitle") %>% 
      hc_xAxis(categories = m_data$x) %>% 
      hc_plotOptions(
        series = list(
          point = list(
            events = list(
              drop = JS("function(){
                        Shiny.onInputChange('xaxis_name', this.category)
                        Shiny.onInputChange('yaxis_name', this.y)          
                        }")))
          ,stickyTracking = FALSE
          ),
        column = list(
          stacking = "normal"
        ),
        line = list(
          cursor = "ns-resize"
        )) %>%
      hc_add_series(       
        data = m_data$myYax , name = "Downloads",draggableY = TRUE
      ) %>%
      hc_add_series(       
        data = m_data$myZax , name = "Downloads",draggableY = TRUE
      ) 
    hc    
  })
})
```

ui.R

```
    library(shiny)

shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
            titlePanel("High Charter plotting"),  
            highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "500px"),
            textOutput("text1"),
            textOutput("text2"),
            tableOutput("view")            
           )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what if I understand your question 100%. But I want to gives some recommendations and I hope it helps with your issue.

1. Instead of send 2 `Shiny.onInputChange` you cand send one in doing a javascript object which is returned like a list into R:

   ```
   Shiny.onInputChange('hcinput', { id: this.series.name, x: this.category, y: this.y })
   ```

   This is a little more clear the code and the shiny server.
2. So in the `output$view` you can do something like:

   ```
   output$view <- renderTable({
     colname <- ifelse(input$hcinput$id == "Downloads1", "myYax", "myZax")
     m_data[x==input$hcinput$x][[colname]] = input$hcinput$y                      
     m_data
   })
   ```

Let discuss if you solve your issue.

Thanks for test the package!

Comment: I tried this ad it works brilliantly. One small change I had to do was 

output$view <- renderTable({
  colname <- ifelse(input$hcinput$id == "Downloads1", "myYax", "myZax")
  m_data[x==input$hcinput$x][[colname]] <<- input$hcinput$y                      
  m_data
})

Comment: I am using the <<- operator instead of <- or =. If I use <- or = the myYax datatable gets overwritten with the original values if I drag the myZax line.

Appreciate the work on the package. I probably need to understand javascript too.

Comment: Never is a bad thing learn other languages especially if is javascript. Maybe the <<- issue is solver if you use a reactive expression to get the data http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson6/. Cheers!